# Populate ListPreference with a list of supported camera picture sizes

Tags: android, camera, preferenceactivity, preference, listpreference

I'm in the middle of developing a camera app, and what I need to do is provide a list of resolutions compatible with the user's device. Getting that list is no problem, I can just use the getSupportedPictureSizes() method. However the bit I'm stuck on is populating a ListPreference with that list.

The ListPreference is created in an .xml file which is used in my Settings PreferenceActivity by calling addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.cam_settings). Any ideas how I can make this ListPreference populate using the list of supported picture sizes?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Still looking for this answer ! please help ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you need to populate the [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html) `programatically`. here is a [**LINK**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/preference/PreferencesFromCode.html)

Comment: Thanks Sam that looks like its the right stuff. Would it be possible with this method to just add a single ListPreference to an existing PreferenceScreen created in an .xml. Or will I have to create the entire thing programatically?

Comment: Ok I got it working. I got an instance of the ListPreference by using getPreferenceScreen().findPreference() then did setEntries and setEntryValues in the onCreate method of my PreferenceActivity. Thanks for the help!